# Django ModelForm ImageField

Tags: django, forms

I have a model and a form (forms.ModelForm) in which I have an ImageField. The model resembles:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    .
    .
    business_image = ImageField(
        max_length=128, 
        upload_to=upload_business_image_handler,
        height_field='business_image_height',
        width_field='business_image_width'
        )
    business_image_height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_image_width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    .
    .
```

The accompanying form:

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, branch_list = None, country_list = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        # create the MultipleChoiceField choice_list based on language
        self.fields['branch'].choices = branch_list
        self.fields['country'].choices = country_list
        self.postdata = data
        self.files = files

    business_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'50', 'class': 'address'}), required=True)

    #business_image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput())
```

The last line in the form is commented out because forms.ClearableFileInput() is the default widget for FileFields and ImageFields.

Now when this form is used to edit an existing record the image in the template is shown as follows:

```
Currently: <image_url>
Change: <browse_button>
```

I would like to change the text-labels 'Currently' and 'Change' and instead of showing the image_url I would like to show the image.

Of course I can copy and modify the code of 'class ClearableFileInput(FileInput)' found in 'site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py' but I am wondering if that's the way to accomplish this.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Now I have looked at the code of 'class ClearableFileInput(FileInput)'

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution to the same problem.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import escape, conditional_escape
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput, Input, CheckboxInput

class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        substitutions = {
            #uncomment to get 'Currently'
            'initial_text': "", # self.initial_text, 
            'input_text': self.input_text,
            'clear_template': '',
            'clear_checkbox_label': self.clear_checkbox_label,
            }
        template = '%(input)s'
        substitutions['input'] = Input.render(self, name, value, attrs)

        if value and hasattr(value, "url"):
            template = self.template_with_initial
            substitutions['initial'] = ('<img src="%s" alt="%s"/>'
                                        % (escape(value.url),
                                           escape(force_unicode(value))))
            if not self.is_required:
                checkbox_name = self.clear_checkbox_name(name)
                checkbox_id = self.clear_checkbox_id(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_name'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_id'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_id)
                substitutions['clear'] = CheckboxInput().render(checkbox_name, False, attrs={'id': checkbox_id})
                substitutions['clear_template'] = self.template_with_clear % substitutions

        return mark_safe(template % substitutions)
```

and then just use the extended widget:

```
business_image = forms.ImageField(widget=CustomClearableFileInput())
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my version of an imageInput that shows the image and doesn't allow for clearing the image

Just have to specify in the form class that the field has `widget=NonClearableImageInput()`

```
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class NonClearableImageInput(FileInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        template = '%(input)s'
        data = {'input': None, 'url': None}
        data['input'] = super(NonClearableImageInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)

        if hasattr(value, 'url'):
            data['url'] = conditional_escape(value.url)
            template = '%(input)s <img src="%(url)s">'

        return mark_safe(template % data)
```

Comment: Hi, I have used this version. But I have a question. I am rendering the form manually. I am getting the old pic as desired. add above that pic I am getting a button "Choose File" and a help text "no file selected". Is there any way that I can change the text to "Upload Photo" and remove the help text. I also move the button below the displayed pic. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put this into the template form

```
{% if business.business_image %}
   <img src="{{ business.business_image.url }}" title="{{ business.business_name}}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes that would display the image in the template but the the 2 items I mentioned, Currently: <image_url> and Change: <browse_button> would still be in the template.