# Overriding url() from ImageField

Tags: django, forms, django-templates, imagefield

I have a image field

```
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar", null=True, blank=True)
```

and using view

```
class EditView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
model = MysiteUser
form_class = MysiteUserForm
pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
template_name = 'update_form.html'
success_url = '/myprofile/'
success_message = "Zmiany zostały wprowadzone."

def form_valid(self, form):
    image_to_del = MysiteUser.objects.get(username=form.instance)
    print("Na dysku plik", image_to_del.avatar)
    print("Formularz i pole 'avatar'", form.instance.avatar)
    if form.instance.avatar != self.request.user.avatar:
        self.request.user.avatar.delete()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

in template form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

I want change link like below

```
<p><label for="id_avatar">Zdjecie:</label> Now: <a href="/media/avatar/n.jpg">avatar/n.jpg</a>
```

on image, how can I do this?

Comment: When I try update image in template I have link to this image and I want picture in this place. See link below https://postimg.org/image/mok8kdx6f/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ModelForm ImageField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822111/django-modelform-imagefield)

Comment: This example is not easy to understand but I will try. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it is to complecated to me. Is there any simplest example to change me code? :/